# How can I save Pending Changes?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table `Infos` that stores some user information, the user can update his data but needs Administrator validation first,
the primary key of `Infos` is the referenced a lot in some others tables

Wy question is where chould I store the pending information that need validation ?

Is it a good idea to store them as JSON in a column ?

Answer (score 1):

Treat this as a data modeling question.  If the user information requires validation before it can be used in the application, introduce a Infos_UpdateRequest table or somesuch, that the administrator can use, and if approved copy the values from there to Infos.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `Infos_Pending` `table` with the same schema as `Infos` and the `primary key` being also a `foreign key` to `Infos`. So, your admins could load the pending records:

- approval would first `update` the `Infos` record with the `Infos_Pending` values and then `delete` the `Infos_Pending` record
- rejection would simply remove the `Infos_Pending` record

Comment: what about  the other tables that reference the primary key of the Infos table,
should i create a X_Pending for them also , because here a lot of them ?

Comment: No.  They always refer to the main Infos table.

Comment: @yyhnfd as David Browne correctly pointed out, all your references would point to the original `Infos` table and you would only create another table to store the pending change suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at adding a pending approval and is active column to your table.
It would then be easy to identify which of your rows should be displayed. You could even keep older rows around for undo/history purposes.
This would mean you'd need to make changes to the sprocs/code used at your display layer, though.
I would suggest not using json or xml unless it's a situation where you always intend to chnage the entire set of values in contains.